# How to update users address with multiple columns

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to update the users address, which is in multiple different columns, one for each part of the address.

It doesn't produce any errors in the error_log, nor the site, and when I click submit all it does is refresh and show a blank page.

```
$Street = (!empty($_POST['street'])) ? $_POST['street'] : false;
$City = (!empty($_POST['city'])) ? $_POST['city'] : false;
$State = (!empty($_POST['state'])) ? $_POST['state'] : false;
$ZIP = (!empty($_POST['ZIP'])) ? $_POST['ZIP'] : false;
$Submit = (!empty($_POST['submit'])) ? true : false;
$ErrorArray = array();
if ($Submit) {
    if (!$Street || !$City || !$State || !$ZIP) {
        if (!$Street) {
            array_push($ErrorArray, 'Please enter your Street Number.');
        } if (!$City) {
            array_push($ErrorArray, 'Please enter a City');
        } if (!$State) {
            array_push($ErrorArray, 'Please enter a State.');
        } if (!$ZIP) {
            array_push($ErrorArray, 'Please enter a ZIP.');
        }
    }
    else {

        $UpdateAdd = $db->prepare("UPDATE User SET User.Street, User.City, User.State, User.ZIP VALUES(':Street', ':City', ':State', ':ZIP') WHERE User.ID = '".$gU->ID."'");
        $UpdateAdd->bindParam(':Street', $Street, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $UpdateAdd->bindParam(':City', $City, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $UpdateAdd->bindParam(':State', $State, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $UpdateAdd->bindParam(':ZIP', $ZIP, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $UpdateAdd->execute();
        array_push($ErrorArray, 'Address Updated!');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're pushing error messages into the array but you aren't doing anything with the array.  It's like putting values into a variable without printing the variable or writing the variable anywhere.

Comment: The array is echo'd further on down the page. 

';
       if (!empty($ErrorArray)) {
        echo '
        <center>
        <h5 class="text-muted">
        '.implode('<br>', $ErrorArray).'
        </h5>
        </center>
        ';
       } echo '

Comment: Where are you instantiating $db?  Did you make sure the connection was successful?

Comment: I have a page being included at the beginning on line 1, didnt display it here, and Yes the connection is successful because I have multiple other things connecting to it.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you aren't passing a post value for 'submit'.

Comment: Try put an 'else' statement for the main 'if' statement and print an error message for that.

Comment: I'm not seeing any use of database error display, as putting the single quotes around the placeholders may be throwing sql prepare errors.

Comment: I took the single quotes out and still haven't received any errors.

Comment: You state: *"It doesn't produce any errors in the error_log, nor the site, and when I click submit all it does is refresh and show the page blank."* - That's because you're not using proper error handling. Consult the duplicate to look at what you did wrong and Google "string literals mysql" and you will see it there also and at the same time, you'd of learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML form and make sure your submit button has a name attribute of  'submit'?

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

After that check, change the PHP line from:

```
$Submit = (!empty($_POST['submit'])) ? true : false;
```

To:

```
$Submit = (isset($_POST['submit'])) ? true : false;
```

Since you are checking for existance instead of a value for that input.

Comment: Checked the submit tag, and everything looked fine, changed the $Submit to
$Submit = (isset($_POST['submit'])) ? true : false;
and it did the same thing, refreshed, didn't update the database and left a blank page.

Comment: TEST: if ($Submit) { echo 'submit: true<br>'; if (!$Street || !$City || !$State || !$ZIP) { echo 'field test: true'; exit;

Comment: It refreshes the page and page is blank.

Comment: Using `empty()` against possible empty inputs is best and especially for what they're using now. However, should there be any radio/checkboxes, then using `isset()` is best for those.